# UITableViewCell selection behaviour changes when selectedBackgroundView is set

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` which is loaded from a xib, with a handful of labels and image views. I notice that when the `.selectedBackgroundView` property is set (in `-awakeFromNib`), interaction with the cell is only possible when touching on the labels or image views within the cell.

Trying to touch any blank space in the cell does nothing. Not setting `.selectedBackgroundView` returns the behaviour to normal.

Does anyone have a fix for this? (Mine currently is to place an empty `UILabel` over the entire contents of my cell)

Comment: What UIView class do you use as selectedBackgroundView? Sounds like that view captures all user events. Have you tried setting `userInteractionEnabled = false` for that view?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I intend to use a `UIVisualEffectView`, but even a simple `UIView` (with interaction disabled), has the same effect.